# Using expressions in Plot with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, scoping

The following works exactly as advertised:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[5 Cos[Pi t] Sin[Pi x], {x, 0, 2},
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}],
 {t, 0, 4}]
```

However, if I use an expression in a variable instead of explicitly in the `Plot` command, that is...

```
wave = 5 Cos[Pi t] Sin[Pi x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[wave, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}],
 {t, 0, 4}]
```

... then the plot is blank. However, I can get this to work by replacing `t` with a different variable and manipulating on that instead:

```
wave = 5 Cos[Pi t] Sin[Pi x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[wave /. t -> tt, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotRange -> {-5, 5}],
 {tt, 0, 4}]
```

Does anybody out there understand why I can't use the second example?

Answer (score 2):

It is a scoping issue. The `t` associated with the control is localized to the `Manipulate` whereas the `t` in the definition of `wave` is in the global context. Make `wave` an explicit function of `t`

```
wave[t_] = 5 Cos[Pi t] Sin[Pi x];
Manipulate[Plot[wave[t], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}], {t, 0, 4}]
```